# Strtotime doesn't work and gives back 1970 and 2019 to 2024

Tags: php, jquery

I am making a select box which will have the options of the past 18 years and this select will be appended every time the user clicks a button.

I created a select box which does this using php and this code which is inside the select:

```
<?php
    for($x=1; $x<=18; $x++){
       $year = date('Y', strtotime(date('Y').'-'.$x.'year'));
       echo '<option value='.$year.'>'.$year.'</option>';
    }
?>
```

However it gives me this: http://puu.sh/nciOj/6fbcd52435.png.

I have tried looking on other posts but none of them seem to help and I have tried looking elsewhere on the internet as well. I have tried taking out `year` and that didn't work. I also tried moving the `$x++;` to inside the the for loop.

What I want to happen is when you click on the select box it will show you the past 18 years. I am sorry if this is a really easy or really stupid question!

Comment: `$year = date('Y') - $x;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're currently passing a badly formed string to `strtotime()`, causing it to return incorrect timestamps.

`date('Y') . '-' . $x . 'year'` would read literally as `2016-1year, 2016-2year` etc. All you need to do is get the current year using `date('Y')`, and subtract `$x` from it. So `2016 - 1, 2016 - 2 etc.`

`$year = date('Y') - $x;`